# Таблица стилей для QProgressBar в PyQt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qss, qprogressbar

[image: Текущий]

Делаю приложение в полностью отличном от *Windows* стиле, то есть делаю стиль всех виджетов своим, с помощью `QSS` и **`файлов.png`** . 
И вот пришла пора изменять `QProgressBar` и я ничего не смог сделать.

Дайте пожалуйста пример или ссылку на пример, каким образом можно заменить изображение на баре (точно как в *Unity*, с помощью **`.png`** файлов). Заранее спасибо всем.

Зеленый бар - такой имеется сейчас, синий - просто в качестве примера, какой я хочу (цель просто сделать из **`.png`** файла(-ов) его, неважно какое именно изображение).

[image: пример]

Comment: 1. приведите пожалуйста пример изображения, которое покажет что вы хотите получить. 2. Ответьте пожалуйста,  почему вы не реагируете на ответы, которые вам предоставляют, я имею ввиду ваши предыдущие вопросы.

Comment: @S.Nick не реагировал потому что ответы мне не подходили, а за время, в течение которого мне отвечали, я уже сам все проблемы решал

Comment: Ну и хам((((((.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore    import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setValue(0)
        
        if self.minimum() != self.maximum():
            self.timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.onTimeout)
            self.timer.start(randint(1, 3) * 1000)

    def onTimeout(self):
        if self.value() >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.timer.deleteLater()
            del self.timer
            return
        self.setValue(self.value() + 1)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100, objectName="RedProgressBar"))
        layout.addWidget(  
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=0, objectName="RedProgressBar"))

        layout.addWidget(
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100, textVisible=False,
                        objectName="GreenProgressBar"))
        layout.addWidget(
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=0, textVisible=False,
                        objectName="GreenProgressBar"))

        layout.addWidget(
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100, textVisible=False,
                        objectName="BlueProgressBar"))
        layout.addWidget(
            ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=0, textVisible=False,
                        objectName="BlueProgressBar"))


StyleSheet = '''
#RedProgressBar {
    text-align: center;            
}
#RedProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #F44336;
}

#GreenProgressBar {
    min-height: 12px;
    max-height: 12px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#GreenProgressBar::chunk {
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #009688;
}

#BlueProgressBar {
    border: 2px solid #2196F3;     
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#BlueProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    width: 10px;                   
    margin: 0.5px;
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(700, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так, вроде бы то, что надо. спасибо